# Can Spring Controller change the url of browser?

Tags: spring, spring-security, redirect

I am using Spring controllers to return the name of views, like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/login","/login.do"})
public ModelAndView showLoginForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    String username = getUsername();
    if(!username.equals("anonymousUser")){
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/home"); 
    }
    return new ModelAndView("login");
}
```

My application is running in this domain (example) **www.localhost:8080/App/home**
and after second login, i need to invalidade the first login and redirect to **www.localhost:8080/App/login**. This is possible to do in server code?

If i am in home page and return new ModelAndView("login"), the browser url isn't modified. why?

Comment: What do you mean "second login"?

Comment: secong login is when do make login in any browser and after makes login in another browser

Comment: You are probably looking for Concurrency control: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#concurrent-sessions

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and use this:

```
return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("login"));
```

If it's not work for your case, you can try absolute path.